# Is there any way to combine two different functions to one function in R?

Tags: r, function

I have two different R functions (myDat and loading). Is there any way to combine these two functions to one function in R?

```
myDat <- function(filename) {
   dat <-readModels(filename, what = "parameters")$parameters  
   dat <- filter(as.data.frame(dat$unstandardized), grepl("BY|Intercepts", paramHeader))

   return(dat)
}

dat2 <- myDat("cfa.out")

loading <- function(loading) {
  loading <- dat2 %>% 
  filter(grepl("BY", paramHeader)) %>% 
  select(c(param, est)) %>% 
  separate(param, c("loading","time")) %>%
  mutate(time = paste0('time',time)) %>% 
  spread(loading, est)

  return(loading)
}

loading(dat2)
```

Comment: If any of the answers below are satisfactory, then you should consider marking one of them as accepted :)

Comment: All of them are very helpful. I really appreciate all the answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you so much for all the helps. It was really helpful. I finally made a function that I wanted based on you guys' comments and suggestions.

```
MIEstimate <- function(x,n) {

 dat <-readModels(x, what = "parameters")$parameters
 dat <- filter(as.data.frame(dat$unstandardized), grepl("BY|Intercepts", paramHeader))

 if(n == 1) { 
  # loading
 loading <- dat %>% 
  filter(grepl("BY", paramHeader)) %>% 
  select(c(param, est)) %>% 
  separate(param, c("loading","time")) %>%
  mutate(time = paste0('time',time)) %>% 
  # spread(loading, est)
  pivot_wider(names_from = "loading",values_from = "est")
return(loading)

} else if(n == 2) {
# intercepts
intercept <- dat %>% 
  filter(grepl("Intercepts", paramHeader)) %>% 
  select(c(param, est)) %>% 
  separate(param, c("intercept","time")) %>%
  mutate(time = paste0('time',time)) %>% 
  # spread(intercept, est)
  pivot_wider(names_from = "intercept",values_from = "est")
return(intercept)
  }
}

MIEstimate("cfa.out", 1)
MIEstimate("cfametric.out", 2)
```

one thing though....
when I used spread() function, the final table time order is like this- not by small to larger
      time V1    V2
1  time133  1 1.038
2  time175  1 0.988
3   time19  1 0.954
4  time224  1 1.005
5   time29  1 0.974
6   time39  1 1.032
7    time5  1 0.995
8   time51  1 0.998
9   time61  1 0.987
10  time75  1 0.992
11  time91  1 0.987

but pivot_wider() works properly. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference you perhaps could have supplied some example data in order to showcase the problem. As i read your question, you're looking for a way to compose two functions (i.e. `h(x) = g(f(x))`. This can be done as follows:

```r
myDat <- function(filename) {
  dat <- readModels(filename, what = "parameters")$parameters  
  dat <- filter(as.data.frame(dat$unstandardized), 
                grepl("BY|Intercepts", paramHeader))
  return(dat)
}

loading <- function(data) {
  data %>% 
    filter(grepl("BY", paramHeader)) %>% 
    select(c(param, est)) %>% 
    separate(param, c("loading","time")) %>%
    mutate(time = paste0('time',time)) %>% 
    spread(loading, est)
}

combined <- purrr::compose(loading, myDat)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can have everything in single pipe.  After extracting the 'parameters',
`pull` the 'unstandardized', convert to `data.frame`, then `filter` the 'paramHeader` where the values are 'BY' or 'Intercepts', and combine with the rest of the pipe from the second function

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
loadingNew <- function(filename) {
   readModels(filename, what = "parameters")$parameters  %>%
    pull('unstandardized') %>%
    as.data.frame %>%        
    filter(str_detect(paramHeader, "BY|Intercepts")) %>%   # not clear about two filter
    filter(grepl("BY", paramHeader)) %>% 
    select(param, est) %>% 
    separate(param, c("loading","time")) %>%
    mutate(time = str_c('time',time)) %>% 
    spread(loading, est)
    # or use pivot_wider
    #pivot_wider(names_from = loading, values_from = est)


}

loadingNew("cfa.out")
```

Comment: I don't think you have enough points yet +1.  That being said, having modular separate functions isn't always a bad thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I would go by modular functions.  Here,  I am not sure why the  OP wanted to combine.  May be to reduce the code chunk